# Conditionally add images to bubble chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, conditional-statements

I need to mass produce bubble charts for a large set of peer groups, where each chart shows anonymized peer group data but highlights the group of interest with their team logo. I'd like to automate this with VBA but am wondering if it's even possible to conditionally add a picture to the bubble of interest in each chart? Right now it's a manual process and takes quite a lot of time.

For example, in chart 1, Team A is the team of interest and has their logo on their bubble while the remaining bubbles are the same solid color. In chart 2, Team B is the team of interest, etc.

Comment: try to capture a macro while you're doing it manually. If you can record it and also you can clearly define the conditions then it's surely possible to do it with VBA.

Comment: Thanks, Mate. I've tried that, but it's selecting the bubble of interest to which to apply the logo that's hanging me up. From the macro, the bubbles look to be assigned a number, but even if I hard coded the numbers in the VBA, I'd have to redo it every month to account for new and changing data.

Comment: post the macro and some sample data, and maybe we can help to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment.  But part of the issue is that you are regenerating the data and charts every time.  So the solution to use is usually "indirection".  Solve a simpler problem.

Could you have a hidden sheet that has all of the logos on it.  Next to the logos is the number that corresponds to that logo (either the logo or the filename of the logo).

Next, write a macro that, if those numbers are correct, assigns the logo you want properly (ie, you just update that sheet, and use that sheet as your array in the VBA).

Finally, if when you send the sheet out, you only ever update ONE logo, then I would make that either part of the filename (and use it in a formula) or put it in a more visible cell.  Then your linkage is done.  One change on that cell, hit the macro and you are good to go.

Without seeing a bit more of the code you are working with.  I can't give more help.

Comment: Thanks for this, @captainkirk! I see where you're going with it and will give it a try. I haven't started the VBA yet but plan to this week and will follow up then.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. It started with needing to set up my data with two defined series, where one series is the group of interest and the second is the peer groups and then to conditionally populate cells in my data table based on the group. The set-up took a lot of time to figure out and looks exhaustive in the instructions below, but it's actually not that bad.

[image: Snapshot of table setup]

Everything highlighted in blue is a formula, so here's how I did it:

1. In column B, I used a formula to identify which series is which: =IF(A5<>A$1,"Peers","Group")
2. Entered my X and Y values (columns C and D).
3. Set my bubble size (column E) to auto-adjust based on the series: =IF(A5=A$1,1000,250)
4. Used columns F and G to trim decimal places.
5. Columns H through L reflect the actual data series set-up based on whether the group is a peer or the group of interest.
6. The X's will always remain the same, so I linked column H to the original X-axis value: =C5
7. Column I pulls the appropriate Y value if it's a peer group: =IF($B5=$I3,$D5,NA())
8. Column J sets the peer group bubble size: =IF(ISNA($I5),NA(),$E5)
9. Column K pulls the appropriate Y value if it's the group of interest: =IF($B5=$K$3,$D5,NA())
10. Column L sets the group of interest bubble size: =IF(ISNA($K5),NA(),$E5)
11. Column M sets all bubble sizes equal and is used for the final chart creation where all groups and their logos are displayed together.
12. Cells O4 (=VLOOKUP(A1,Logos!A:B,2,FALSE)) and P4 (=IF(O4=1,"group1",IF(O4=2,"group2",IF(O4=3,"group3",IF(O4=4,"group4"))))) identify and pull in the correct logo when the group of interest is selected.

I then had to set up and link in all my logos/images on a separate tab ("Logos"). Oz du Soleil's YouTube video on "Select an image based on a cell value" was immensely helpful in getting this done. I don't have enough reputation to post the direct link.

I created and formatted my bubble charts then selected the data as needed for each series using columns H (X-axis), I/K (Y-axis), and J/L (Z-axis for bubble size).

For my full group logo chart, I needed only one series because all bubbles would be the same size. I used columns C, D, and M for the X, Y, and Z-axes, respectively. I then applied each group logo to their respective bubbles.

The code itself ended up being pretty straight-forward after the setup:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim Cells As Range

'This section looks up each group name on the tab and cycles through the loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
    iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 4 To iLastRow - 1 'Group names start in A5

        'Selects, copies, and pastes the next group name in the list
        Sheets("Groups").Select
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Copy
        Range("A1").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues

        'Selects, copies, and pastes the group logo onto the bubble
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 7")).Select
            Selection.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
            Selection.paste

        'Variables needed for directory and file names
        GroupName = Sheets("Groups").Range("A1")
        yearmo = Sheets("Groups").Range("A2")

        'Will create a new folder for the final images if it doesn't already exist
        If Len(Dir("DirPath\" & yearmo, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "DirPath\" & yearmo
        End If

        'Set up image file names
        Dim NewFileName As String
        NewFileName = "\" & yearmo & " - " & GroupName & " - X_Y.jpg"

        'Selects and saves the bubble chart as a JPG
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
        ActiveChart.Export "DirPath\" & yearmo & NewFileName

    Next i
End With

    'After all individual bubble have been created, need to
    'set up state file name to generate image with all logos for the state
    Dim StateFileName As String
    StateFileName = "\" & yearmo & " - STATE - X_Y.jpg"

    'Selects and saves the state bubble chart as a JPG
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
    ActiveChart.Export "DirPath\" & yearmo & StateFileName
```

[image: Populated bubble chart]

I opted against using labels in the chart because trying to get them to position dynamically didn't seem worth the effort. I instead went with creating linked text boxes below the chart.

Hopefully this is of some help to others; it's certainly a massive time saver from manual updates.